# build error netflix fenzo library

Tags: gradle, netflix

The Netflix fenzo (https://github.com/Netflix/Fenzo) build fails complaining on gradle plugin from netflix not available.

Stack trace below

```
> Configure project :
Inferred project: fenzo, version: 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/UKHANVA/git/Fenzo/build.gradle' line: 32

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'fenzo'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'nebula.plugin.info.dependencies.DependenciesInfoPlugin']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'DependenciesInfoPlugin'.
      > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.strategy.DefaultVersionComparator.asStringComparator() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
        Possible solutions: asVersionComparator()

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
```

Comment: Does my explanation below answer the question for you?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are using the version of gradle you have in your path:

```
gradle build
```

Try running the build with the gradle wrapper script in the repository:

```
./gradlew build
```

The version of gradle used by the wrapper is configured in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. Fenzo is using 2.13 which is quite old.

By experimenting with the wrapper version, I found that it builds successfully with Gradle 2.x & 3.x but not 4.x.

Gradle 4.0 gave me the exact same error as above. 4.8 also failed but with a different error.